# Filter SQL result?

Tags: mysql, sql

i got same emails  in status 3 and 1. and i need to show emails only of status 3
with this query is showing me in page of status 3 also email that with status 1

Here is my query:

```
 SELECT live_customers.Id, live_customers.date,
        live_customers.firstname, live_customers.lastname, live_customers.phone,
        live_customers.phone2, live_customers.email, live_customers.num_sellers, 
        live_customers.sell_date,live_customers.public_description,  
        live_customers.public_image, live_customers.price,
        live_customers.takanon, live_customers.confirm_mail_sent, live_customers.paid,
        live_customers.shirt_size, live_customers.shirt_size_extra, 
        live_customers.stand_rent, live_customers.refunded, live_customers.call1,
        live_customers.call2, live_customers.notes,
        live_customers.auth_number, live_customers.hasContact, live_customers.IP, 
        live_customers.status, live_status.name AS StatusName, 
        live_status.color AS StatusColor, live_compound.name AS CompoundName 
   FROM live_customers
        INNER JOIN live_status 
                   ON live_status.Id=live_customers.status          
        INNER JOIN
        LEFT JOIN live_compound 
                   ON live_compound.Id=live_customers.compound_id
   WHERE live_customers.status='3'                         
   GROUP BY 
        live_customers.Id 
   ORDER BY 
        live_customers.Id DESC 
   LIMIT 0,30
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN` without any condition, Query is wrong , as well as explain your question properly

Comment: And what is the problem with your query? Does it work? Does it not work? provide more information and details.

Comment: what is the datatype of status column is character or numeric

Comment: `INNER JOIN LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: homeless JOIN looking for warm family?

Comment: What's the question? What's the problem?

Comment: i got same emails  in status 3 and 1. and i need to show emails only of status 3

Answer (score 0):

you have mixed both Inner Join and Left Join ...

Try this

```
SELECT live_customers.Id, live_customers.date,
        live_customers.firstname, live_customers.lastname, live_customers.phone,
        live_customers.phone2, live_customers.email, live_customers.num_sellers, 
        live_customers.sell_date,live_customers.public_description,  
        live_customers.public_image, live_customers.price,
        live_customers.takanon, live_customers.confirm_mail_sent, live_customers.paid,
        live_customers.shirt_size, live_customers.shirt_size_extra, 
        live_customers.stand_rent, live_customers.refunded, live_customers.call1,
        live_customers.call2, live_customers.notes,
        live_customers.auth_number, live_customers.hasContact, live_customers.IP, 
        live_customers.status, live_status.name AS StatusName, 
        live_status.color AS StatusColor, live_compound.name AS CompoundName 
   FROM live_customers
        INNER JOIN live_status 
                   ON live_status.Id=live_customers.status          
        INNER JOIN live_compound 
                   ON live_compound.Id=live_customers.compound_id
   WHERE live_customers.status='3'                         
   GROUP BY 
        live_customers.Id 
   ORDER BY 
        live_customers.Id DESC 
   LIMIT 0,30
```

Comment: this is good but it is same query as i have the problem is that i got same emails in status 3 and 1. and i need to show emails only of status 3 i mean if email got status 3 and 1 , i am not showing him

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution of my problem. here it is.
 Hope this will be useful to some one

```
   SELECT  live_customers.Id, live_customers.date,
           live_customers.firstname, live_customers.lastname, live_customers.phone,
           live_customers.phone2, live_customers.email, live_customers.num_sellers, 
           live_customers.sell_date,live_customers.public_description,  
           live_customers.public_image, live_customers.price,
           live_customers.takanon, live_customers.confirm_mail_sent, live_customers.paid,
           live_customers.shirt_size, live_customers.shirt_size_extra, 
           live_customers.stand_rent, live_customers.refunded, live_customers.call1,
           live_customers.call2, live_customers.notes,
           live_customers.auth_number, live_customers.hasContact, live_customers.IP, 
           live_customers.status, live_status.name AS StatusName, 
           live_status.color AS StatusColor, live_compound.name AS CompoundName 
   FROM live_customers
        INNER JOIN live_status 
               ON live_status.Id=live_customers.status          
        INNER JOIN live_compound 
               ON live_compound.Id=live_customers.compound_id                   

        WHERE live_customers.status='3'  
        AND live_customers.Email NOT IN (SELECT Email FROM live_customers WHERE status=1)                  
        GROUP BY 
    live_customers.Id 
        ORDER BY 
    live_customers.Id DESC
```

Comment: Note that the use of GROUP BY in the absence of any aggregating functions is often a sign that you don't really know what you're doing.

Comment: in this case i now what i'm doing and what i need. but any way thanks for comment